# Delphi Connectors replacement

Tags: pontiac, connector, sunfire

I recently experienced a major electrical shortage on my car, a Pontiac Sunfire 2003.

A 16 pins delphi connector started to burn up and I had to throw water at it. This connector seems to be powering the front lights as well as the horn and probably other things that I did not test.

Do I need to buy back a connector to replace it ? Or can I just put the wires together with tape and expect to have average results ?

They also seems to be pretty tight and depending on the damages, I might have to remove some cabling. What would be the common way to extend those cables to make them reach each other ? (I am thinking about extending them with cabling and other delphi connectors if necessary)

Thanks

Comment: In my experience as a 14 year-old with an '81 Civic, _Tape Works_. However, I'd recommend you buy new connectors to replace the old ones (they're really cheap, and it'll save you time later when you need to unplug them.) If any wires are burnt and won't reach, you can cut them past the burnt area, solder new wires on to extend them, then surround the solder connection with heat shrink to insulate it. If that sounds like too much work, you can also get crimp wire connectors, which are mindlessly simple to use, but less reliable than soldering the wires.

Comment: Really appreciate your input, I think I will go with crimps connection of type male/female that are easily unplug-able. Easiest way for me to do the job as a beginner. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Also, if the wires are tight at all, just extend them. Things in a car shake a lot, and tight wires will just pull out of crimp connectors, or break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Tape Works*. However,

I'd recommend you buy new connectors to replace the old ones (they're really cheap, and it'll save you time later when you need to unplug them.)

If any wires are burnt and won't reach, you can cut them past the burnt area, solder new wires on to extend them, then surround the solder connection with heat shrink to insulate it. If that sounds like too much work, you can also get crimp wire connectors, which are mindlessly simple to use, but less reliable than soldering the wires.

If the wires barely reach and will have strain on them, extend them. Cars have a lot of vibration, and wires will sometimes pull out of crimp connectors.

[image: crimp wire connectors] [image: Delphi wire connectors]